# Can't install PythonMagic on Mac OS

Tags: c++, python, boost, imagemagick, pythonmagick

I can/t install PythonMagick, all problem is in Boost::Python. I'm installing boost wirh brew:

```
brew install boost
```

also tried to install boost from source:

```
./bootstrap.sh --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/boost --with-libraries=python
./b2 install
```

Every time I configure PythonMagick I'm telling where is boost:

```
./configure --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/PythonMagick CPPFLAGS="-I /usr/local/Cellar/boost/ -I /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.3/include/python2.7/" LDFLAGS=-L/usl/local/lib
```

And I always get error: checking whether the Boost::Python library is available... no

Comment: Nobody can't help me? =((

Comment: No =( just installed wand - http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.3.5/